# Wubi with 14.10 doesn't work - failed to partition the selected disk

Tags: wubi, 14.10

I tried to install Ubuntu 14.10 on my computer with Wubi. The installation appeared to work in Windows, and told me to reboot.

After rebooting the Ubuntu installer continued the installation, until it stopped with an error message: **Failed to partition the selected disk** with the detail **This probably happened because are too many primary partitions in the partition table**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug with the `wubi.exe` released with 14.10. Or to be precise it's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1385930) in one of the programs used by`ubiquity` (the Ubuntu installer). Normally bugs can be fixed, but typically Wubi is never patched mid-release so this bug will remain for the full life-cycle of Ubuntu 14.10.

So, if you have tried to install Ubuntu with Wubi 14.10, it doesn't work and cannot be fixed with any known manual workaround.

Go to the *Add/Remove programs* in the Control Panel in Windows, and double click on the *Ubuntu* entry to completely uninstall Wubi.

**Update**

There is now a manual workaround from *[hakuna_matata](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=1134689)* that is of medium to high difficulty. You have to apply it in Windows, prior to the Ubuntu install phase. See [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2251986) for more information.