# root file system?

Tags: partitioning, wubi, root

tried installing using wubi, CD and usb. Only the wubi and the cd was able to boot, but then a message popped up while verifying, failed to partition the selected disk and no root file system. 
I want my pc to be just Ubuntu. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more details - what version are you trying to install, where did you get the .iso image, at what stage the message popped up?

Comment: Your problem is this: [Wubi with 14.10 doesn't work - failed to partition the selected disk](http://askubuntu.com/questions/547015/wubi-with-14-10-doesnt-work-failed-to-partition-the-selected-disk) But Wubi won't give you what you want (just Ubuntu). So consider this: [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

WUBI doesn't work with Windows 8, and s not recommended anymore (what version of Ubuntu did you install with it anyway? I don't think it's available in the current versions), so don't use that, especially if you want to erase all other OS's (like windows) and leave only Ubuntu.

- Here's the [Ubuntu.com "Download Ubuntu Desktop"](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) page, that has some guides on creating a DVD or USB under the "Easy ways to switch to Ubuntu" heading.
- Another guide on [creating a Bootable USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)
- [A guide on using the Ubuntu Installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall)