# Ubuntu 14.10 wubi installation error

Tags: system-installation, 14.10, wubi

When the installation is almost completed through wubi I get following error:
[Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7mZOK3e8BB7TmhGQ1kzU0N0S28/view?usp=sharing)
Also the log file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7mZOK3e8BB7Q1NHVVhJT0NabjQ/view?usp=sharing)

I am using Win7 pro 64bit

Edit: corrected the link for log file

Comment: your second link is not working, please check coz it asks me to login. people should be able to see that link without login to google drive

Comment: The 12.04 version was the last supported version with wubi. Wubi is supposed to be an easy to install verison, but with all new systems using UEFI and gpt, wubi is not compatible. A few very advanced users have made it work, but now it is not an easy to install system. Better to dual boot. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: Wubi 14.10 [doesn't work](http://askubuntu.com/q/547015/14916) and it appears [you have dynamic drives](http://askubuntu.com/q/179215/14916); you'll need to convert from that before installing a normal dual boot.